# add Autofac extension to throw exception if not appropriately injected into approved type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm attempting to create an Autofac extension method that will throw an exception when a registered type is created for an object that is not an approved object type.

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> OnlyForInheritorsOf<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(
    this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type baseType)
where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
{
    return registration.OnActivated(e =>
    {
        if (!baseType.IsInstanceOfType(??? instance of target/receiver ???))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected to implement");
    });
}
```

`e.Instance` points to the object just created/activated. However, I need the information about the object we're going to give that to. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to specify that some registration need a specific type and other need another one, you should have a look at [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

For example, if you have two implementation for `IFoo`, you can register them like this.

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>().Named<IFoo>("foo1");
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().Named<IFoo>("foo2");
```

And if `Bar` need `Foo1` you can register `Bar` like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<Bar>()
        .As<Bar>()
        .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IFoo), 
                       (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IFoo>("foo1"));
```

Or by specifying the key using an attribute on `Bar` constructor :

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar([WithKey("foo1")]IFoo foo)
    { }
}
```

I don't know your precise scenario, it may require some code refactoring but these changes may be a better things than using a more complex scenario.

---

By the way, if you really want to do what you explain. I wrote some code that use a custom `Parameter` and `Module` that will throw exception if the caller is not of required type for the registration.

```
public static class RegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> OnlyForInheritorsOf<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, Type baseType)
            where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
    {
        registration.RegistrationData.Metadata.Add(RestrictingRegistrationModule.MetadataKey, baseType);
        return registration;
    }
}

public class RestrictingRegistrationModule : Autofac.Module
{
    internal const String MetadataKey = "RestrictedType";


    internal class RestrictedAutowiringParameter : Parameter
    {
        public RestrictedAutowiringParameter(RestrictingRegistrationModule restrictingRegistrationModule)
        {
            this._restrictingRegistrationModule = restrictingRegistrationModule;
        }


        private readonly RestrictingRegistrationModule _restrictingRegistrationModule;


        public override Boolean CanSupplyValue(ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext context, out Func<Object> valueProvider)
        {
            if (pi == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("pi");
            }
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            IInstanceLookup lookup = context as IInstanceLookup;
            if (lookup != null)
            {
                IComponentRegistration registration;
                if (context.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(new TypedService(pi.ParameterType), out registration))
                {
                    Type restrictedType;
                    if (this._restrictingRegistrationModule.RestrictedRegistrations.TryGetValue(registration, out restrictedType))
                    {
                        Type callerType = lookup.ComponentRegistration.Activator.LimitType;
                        if (!(callerType == restrictedType || callerType.IsSubclassOf(restrictedType)))
                        {
                            throw new Exception(String.Format("Registration {0} is not compatible for type {1}", registration, callerType));
                        }
                    }

                    valueProvider = (() => context.ResolveComponent(registration, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>()));
                    return true;
                }
            }

            valueProvider = null;
            return false;
        }
    }


    public RestrictingRegistrationModule()
    {
        this._restrictedRegistrations = new Dictionary<IComponentRegistration, Type>();
    }


    private readonly Dictionary<IComponentRegistration, Type> _restrictedRegistrations;


    public Dictionary<IComponentRegistration, Type> RestrictedRegistrations
    {
        get
        {
            return this._restrictedRegistrations;
        }
    }


    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        Object value;
        if (registration.Metadata.TryGetValue(RestrictingRegistrationModule.MetadataKey, out value))
        {
            this._restrictedRegistrations.Add(registration, (Type)value);
        }

        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Concat(new Parameter[] { new RestrictedAutowiringParameter(this) });
        };
    }

}
```

And you can use this code like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new RestrictingRegistrationModule());
builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<Bar>();
builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().As<Bar2>();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().OnlyForInheritorsOf(typeof(Bar));

IContainer container = builder.Build();

Bar bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
Bar2 bar2 = container.Resolve<Bar2>(); // will throw
```

I have not deeply tested this code,  it is only for fun and education purpose, use it with caution !

Comment: Thank you for the module! That was nontrivial. I'm fully aware of the named instance approach. However, it doesn't scale well.